# change <input> to <select> using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an `<input>`, How do I change it to a `<select>`?

```
 <input id="#input"> to
 <select id="#input">
```

I have tried

```
$("#input").parent().replaceWith('<select id='#input'">" + "</select>")
```

Comment: Why does your ID have a `#` at the front?

Comment: You need to escape that naughty `#`: `$("#\\#input").`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your try example you are replacing input's parent with select.
Second, You have a lot of quotation typos.
That would do:

```
var input = $('#input');
 if(input){
    input.replaceWith("<select id='input'>" + "</select>")
  }
```

Also if you want to keep '#' in your ids, escape them as freedomn-m suggested